# uncountable subcovers of a compact set

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Example of a compact set $K$ and a cover of it by closed sets such that the cover contains no countable subcover of $K$.

So my $K$ would be $[0,1]$ and my cover would be $[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cup[\frac{1}{2},1]$. Would that work?

Comment: I think that countable here includes finite.

Comment: Remember that one-point sets are closed.

Comment: what about $[\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}]$?

Comment: That would not be either as the sets form a sequence and are therefore countable.

Comment: im lost then...

Answer (score 2):

Nope! Because there are 2 items in your cover and that is a countable sub cover.

As every [singleton set is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203728/every-single-point-is-closed/203733) we could consider our cover to be the union of all singleton set for real numbers in $[0,1]$. As the interval $[0,1]$ is not countable over the reals and removing any one of the singleton sets makes it no longer a cover this satisfies the conditions.